# Calculate required chance for each boolean so that the chance for X would be Y

Tags: probability

I am programming a game and in some point I to roll 6 booleans. The chance for true be less than 50% and I want to calculate that chance so there would be a chance of 25% that exactly 2 booleans will come out as true.
I know there are $2^6$ possible options. I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: You can get a sextic equation from the binomial distribution.  It has two real roots in that interval (and two others which are not probabilities plus two complex roots)

Comment: Isn't it impossible to solve a sextic equation?

Comment: Some you can - and this happens to be an example of such a case, though you do not want to as it would be such a mess of cube roots and complex numbers.  Better to use numeric approaches